# How to store an retrieve float from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm having trouble storing and retrieving a float in NSUserDefauts. I store the value, but when I retrieve it, it returns 0.

here's what I tried and didn't work:

```
[pref setFloat:3.0f forKey:@"key"];
float value = [pref floatForKey:@"key"]; //value=0

[pref setFloat:3 forKey:@"key"];
float value = [pref floatForKey:@"key"];//value=0

[pref setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3] forKey:@"key"];
float value = [[pref objectForKey:@"key"]floatValue];//value=0

[pref setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f] forKey:@"key"];
float value = [[pref objectForKey:@"key"]floatValue];//value=0
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried these 4 pieces of code but they all return zero when retrieving the float from NSUserDefaults.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `pref` is almost certainly nil. Show the code where you assign pref. Where is it in relation to the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example in your code is fine, assuming that this line:

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Appears before it. As I suggested in my comment, the behaviour you are seeing suggests that `pref` is nil.

Comment: jrturton, thanks a lot! that was it!! I actually declared pref in my .h file, and synthesized it in my .m file. Can I not do that with NSUserDefault??

Comment: Synthesising just creates the accessor methods.  You still need to assign a value to the property at some point.

Answer (score 9):

**Save**

```
-(void) saveFloatToUserDefaults:(float)x forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setFloat:x forKey:key];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

**Load**

```
-(float) loadFloatFromUserDefaultsForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [userDefaults floatForKey:key];
}
```

**How-To**

```
[self saveFloatToUserDefaults:5.241 forKey:@"myFloat"];
float x = [self loadFloatFromUserDefaultsForKey:@"myFloat"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3] forKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: It is not necessary to convert the float to an `NSNumber` for `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. For Storing

-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender

```
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:fontSlider.value forKey:@"keyFontSize"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

2.For retriving

```
-(void)retrive
{
   NSLog(@"%f",[storedata floatForKey:@"keyFontSize"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` special cases floats as well as a few other native "C" types.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:3 forKey:@"key"];

float value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"key"];
NSLog(@"value: %.0f", value);
```

NSLog output:
value: 3

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (pref) {
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:3 forKey:@"key"];

   //for accessing
   float value = [pref floatForKey:@"key"]; //if key does not exist, value will be zero
}
```

Comment: Wondering why the check for `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` since if that returns `nil` the system is hosed and a wonder it hasn't crashed yet. :-) It is similar to checking if `[NSData data]` returns `nil` which we reasonably don't check.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no one seems to have explicitly resolved the issue the OP had.
The OP had declared `NSUserDefaults` in the `.h` file and was just trying to access it in the `.m` file without actually alloc'ing the pref instance.
For the sake of the beginner programmer, this means in `.h` declare the instance:
`NSUserDefaults * pref;`

and in your `.m` method, put this before trying to access it:

`pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

It seems obvious to some, but can catch you out every now and then. You will ideally put this somewhere like `viewDidLoad`, but if you're accessing methods in that class via something like a shared instance, then in the methods you might benefit from putting

```
if(!pref){ 
pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
}
```

before you need to access it, just to make sure it's been allocated memory.
Hope this helps somebody!