# knowing when the app was last used, iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I would like to add a condition to my app that is based on if the user has used the app in the past week or not. What is the best way to do that? I read somewhere that I should used NSUseDefaults, but not sure how, I am just new to this.

thanks.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553648/nsuserdefaults-storing-and-retrieving-data) might help.

Comment: mmm...not so much...just shows a basic usage of NSUserDefaults. thanks though.

Comment: [And this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957055/how-to-store-an-retrieve-float-from-nsuserdefaults), which shows how to save a float. You can save and restore a date value the same way, or are you looking for someone to actually write the code for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read:

```
self.lastRun = [NSDate distantPast];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"MyAppLastRun"]) {
    self.lastRun = [defaults objectForKey:@"MyAppLastRun"];
}
```

Write:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.lastRun forKey:@"MyAppLastRun"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Compare:

```
if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.lastRun] > X) {
}
```

Note: assumes a property on self of NSDate *lastRun.

Answer (score 2):

Yeh, just stick something in `NSUserDefaults` like so:

```
// When app comes to foreground:

NSDate *lastStartDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lastStartDate"];

if (!lastStartDate) {
    // Never launched
} else if ([lastStartDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < -(60. * 60. * 24. * 7.)) {
    // Do whatever you want if they've not used in past week
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastStartDate"];
```

Comment: So even though lastStartDate stores the "date", if you use it with timeIntervalSinceNow it will be converted to seconds?

Comment: Yes, it returns seconds. However, I find it more intuitive to switch the order so that the interval returns positive seconds not negative. [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:lastStartDate];

Answer (score 2):

You can set a value in the `applicationWillTerminate`: like:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastUsed"];
```

Retrive the value:

```
NSDate *date=(NSDate*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@lastUsed"];
```

Then compare the dates.

Comment: Note that applicationWillTerminate is not guaranteed to be called in all cases.